How can I align solid wood flooring between rooms?
I have a room layout like the diagram below. I am installing solid hardwood flooring (red oak planks with tongue and groove on both short and long edges) in this area. Eventually, all areas in the diagram will have wood floors.

The brown part in the top left is complete and has the wood already, with the final planks terminating right along the door. It's fairly straight and square. Definitely not more than a degree off, and I suspect it's less than 0.1 degree off.
The width of the brown and blue areas is about 12 feet and the drawing is not to exact scale.
I'm not sure what order to do the remaining areas in to minimize unsightly gaps. With the orientation I picked, there will be a few very long rows spanning the grey area and the top of the green area. I wouldn't need to have a transition at the grey/green border, the planks can just continue under the door - although perhaps I should consider adding a transition anyway to simplify things.
The options I see are:

First fill in the blue area. Then do the grey and top of green, and hope that the blue/green border lines up with the brown/grey border. My worry is that the total height of the blue area will end up being not exactly the same as the brown area, and I will have a visible gap along the blue/green border.
Lay out boards for the top of grey and top of green, then all of blue, without nailing. Use this to get an exact measure and cut the topmost row of planks in blue, so that they end exactly 3/4" off the top wall. Then nail top row of blue (which was cut to custom width) and nail downwards. This should ensure I don't get a gap at the blue/green border as in 1.
Do each room separately. Add transition strips in brown/grey, grey/green and blue/green borders even though it's not strictly necessary. Hide gaps/misalignment under the transition strips.

What is the "normal" way to handle this type of situation when installing hardwood flooring planks?
I'm not very experienced with flooring installs, but I have been able to do a pretty good job with the brown room. It looks as good as or slightly better than professional floors in other buildings. With the equipment I have, I can do very precise cuts, alignments and minimize accumulating gaps/misalignment between subsequent rows. The walls are sheet rock installed with average competency, so they are not perfectly square, but so far it's been good enough to not ruin my floor alignment. However, I have noticed that when I need to cut boards lengthwise, this removes the tongue and groove, and although I can get the cut to match up very close, the lack of tongue and groove allows one board to lift up ever so slightly and which is very perceptible to eye and feel. For this reason I want to avoid adjusting row width by cutting boards lengthwise, unless it is adjacent to a wall. Basically, I want to preserve tongue and groove joints between all boards if possible.

Is the crux of all that that you need to nail your product on one side only, so working back into the blue room from the hallway doesn't work?

@isherwood In the diagram, I can only go downwards because of how it must be nailed. I can't go upwards, since I can nail into the grooves, only into tongues. However, I could get around that by laying out the whole room without nailing, and then nailing from the top downwards. The real problem is ensuring that the rows stay neat and aligned, with no large gaps anywhere.

I would not use transition strips. They look amateurish and just aren't necessary when you're already putting in all this effort. @crip659, did you mean chalk lines?

#3 would probably be the easiest. If not #3 then brown to grey to green to blue. Think you got lucky with one room almost perfect. Four rooms will need chalk lines and good measurements. Try before permanent attaching.

I'm not a solid wood flooring expert, but I've seen plenty of it installed. I think I'd reverse direction where needed with a custom spline. By fitting a floating strip you can place boards groove-to-groove and reverse the orientation when you enter the next room (blue in your case).
You might have to do some hand nailing in the first groove to secure it if your nailer doesn't accommodate that profile, but you avoid surface nailing. Then you glue up the spline and carry on as usual.
Read more about reversing direction and backfilling
